# Running Eslint airbnb specific file returns nothing

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm running

```
node_modules/.bin/eslint app.jsx
```

and it returns nothing. I know there are errors on the page however. Anyone know what is going on? I don't even get a message on screen.

If I run:

```
node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext=js --ext=jsx
```

I'll see the errors in app.jsx.

The reason I am doing just a single file is because I just turned on airbnb with eslint on create-react-app and I have a lot of errors to fix I wanted to do it slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your app.jsx is in a "src" folder, right? So you have to add it in your command like this:

```
node_modules/.bin/eslint ./src/app.jsx
```

Nico

Comment: Perfect. That works. A "file not found" message would have been nice :)